# Mock responses from an API available only during a live event

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, unit-testing, mocking

I'm currently writing a backend in Node/Express that will poll a Sports API during football games to get live scores and so on.

Naturally mocking is a technique that has quickly come up during the development of this application.

Up until this point I have used `nock` to intercept HTTP requests to this API and return some JSON that I have written. This is great, and I can test my request functions and API authorization and so on. However the entire testing process and mocking of responses is static, and I have come to a point where I need to mock the dynamic nature of this interaction.

Here are some ideas that I have scratched up so far.

- Create multiple objects locally that will mimick the actual responses from the API:

`var firstResponse = {
   "first_event": "goal"
 }`

`var secondResponse = {
   "first_event": "goal",
   "second_event" : "foul"`

`var thirdResponse = {
   "first_event": "goal",
   "second_event" : "foul",
   "third_event": "goal"`

- Mock the responses over some `x` interval:

  - For the first request respond with fake data `N`
  - For subsequent requests respond with fake data `N + 1`

This is my conceptual understanding of what needs to be done to test this functionality. I'm following TDD so I don't have the function yet - that will most likely result in another post ;-)

I would really appreciate some feedback, hopefully I have presented my problem clearly. If not I am, as always, happy to edit my question with more information.

Thank you all, hope your Monday's are going okay :-)

Comment: you can make a whole fake mock server to test a little lower on the chain, with ways to reset the game and all that.

Comment: Hey thanks. I have no clue where to start with that though. Any pointers?

Comment: at it's simplest, you copy the response from the real API, save it, and make it returned by your server when the relative url you used to fectch it is requested. it need not even parse the GET, just match the whole thing.